# Get text between two annotated tags in ruta

Tags: uima, ruta

How to get data present between two annotated texts?

Sample input:

```
Seller Name  FirstAvenue Mortgage, TN 12230     Contact Name John
```

Code :

```
BLOCK(sellerName) Line{CONTAINS(SellerNameKeyword)} {
    c:ANY+{-PARTOF(SellerNameKeyword), -PARTOF(SellerName)-> 
        CREATE(SellerName, "label"="Seller Name", "value"=c.ct)} 
ContactNameKeyword;
    }
```

This code is not giving any output for SellerName `annotation`

Expected Output : `FirstAvenue Mortgage, TN 12230`

What changes if input is spread across two lines ?

Sample input:

```
Seller Name  FirstAvenue Mortgage, Contact Name John   
             TN 12230              Contact Title Supervisor
```

Code for above mentioned use case:

```
TYPESYSTEM utils.PlainTextTypeSystem;
ENGINE utils.PlainTextAnnotator;

DECLARE Keyword (STRING label);
DECLARE Entry(Keyword keyword);

DECLARE Keyword SellerNameKeyword, SellerNameContextBlocker, ContactNameKeyword;

EXEC(PlainTextAnnotator, {Line,Paragraph});

ADDRETAINTYPE(WS);
Line{->TRIM(WS)};
Paragraph{->TRIM(WS)}; 
REMOVERETAINTYPE(WS);

"Seller Name" -> SellerNameKeyword ( "label" = "Seller Name");
"Contact Title" -> SellerNameContextBlocker("label" = "Seller Name Context Blocker");
"Contact Name" -> ContactNameKeyword("label"= "Contact Name");

DECLARE Entity (STRING label, STRING value);
DECLARE Entity ContactName, SellerName;

BLOCK(line1) Line{CONTAINS(ContactNameKeyword)} {
    ContactNameKeyword c:#{-PARTOF(ContactName)-> CREATE(ContactName,"label"="Contact Name", "value"=c.ct)};
}
SellerNameKeyword c:#{-PARTOF(ContactNameKeyword),-PARTOF(SellerNameContextBlocker),-PARTOF(ContactName) -> 
    CREATE(SellerName,"label"="Seller Name", "value"=c.ct)} SellerNameContextBlocker;
```

Output : `FirstAvenue Mortgage,   Contact Name John     TN 12230`

Expected Output : `FirstAvenue Mortgage, TN 12230`

Please suggest required changes and what I have missed ?

Comment: Input text :`Seller Name  FirstAvenue Mortgage, TN 12230     Contact Name John`

Use wildcard `#` to get data between two annotated text.

`SellerNameKeyword c:#{->CREATE(SellerName,"label"="Seller Name", "value"=c.ct)} ContactNameKeyword ;`

Comment: for 2nd part of question, I tried following but not sure how to add these two annotations together `BLOCK(sellerName1) Line{CONTAINS(SellerNameKeyword)} {
    SellerNameKeyword c:#{->CREATE(SellerName1, "label"= "Seller Name 1", "value"=c.ct)} 
        ContactNameKeyword;
}
BLOCK(sellerName2) Line{CONTAINS(ContactPhoneNoKeyword)} {
    n:#{->CREATE(SellerName2,"label"="Seller Name 2", "value"=n.ct)} ContactTitleKeyword;
}`

Comment: For the second question, which annotations you want to add together? `SellerName1` and `SellerName2`? What do you expect as output?

Comment: SellerName annotator as combination of SellerName1 and SellerName2. Is there any other way to achive this other than this way? I mean just get SellerName without tagging SellerName1 and SellerName2

Comment: `DECLARE Entity SellerName;
SellerNameKeyword c:ANY+{-PARTOF(ContactNameKeyword),-PARTOF(ContactName),-PARTOF(SellerName) ->
     CREATE(SellerName,"label"="Seller Name", "value"=c.ct)} ContactTitleKeyword;` Tried this to get sellerName but didn't work

Comment: Assuming you expect `FirstAvenue Mortgage` to be your `SellerName`, you started correctly by annotating the `SellerNameKeyword`: `DECLARE SellerNameKeyword; "Seller Name" -> SellerNameKeyword`. Afterwards, you have to define the `SellerNameContextBlocker`; whether it is "TN 12230" or "Contact Name" you annotate it as `SellerNameContextBlocker`. Having these building blocks, now, you can finally annotate the seller name: `SellerNameKeyword ANY[0,10]{-PARTOF(SellerNameContextBlocker) -> SellerName} SellerNameContextBlocker;`

Comment: I dont want Contact Name to be part of SellerName, Have already updated question with relevant input and output

Answer (score 0):

Since the information you want to annotate is not sequential in text ("Contact Name John" comes in between) you cannot represent the desired output in CAS as the covered text of a single annotation. 
However, in your case, you might want to join together the text of interest in a feature of the output annotation. For example:

```
DECLARE SellerNameKeyword, ContactNameKeyword, ContactTitleKeyword;
DECLARE SellerName (STRING  value);

"Seller Name" -> SellerNameKeyword;
"Contact Name" -> ContactNameKeyword;
"Contact Title" -> ContactTitleKeyword;

ADDRETAINTYPE(BREAK);
SellerNameKeyword ANY[0,5]{-PARTOF(ContactNameKeyword), -PARTOF(COMMA) -> 
s1:CREATE(SellerName)} COMMA? 
ContactNameKeyword ANY[0,5]{-PARTOF(BREAK)} BREAK? ANY[0,10]{-PARTOF(ContactTitleKeyword) -> 
s2:CREATE(NameId), s1.value=""+s1.ct+s2.ct} ContactTitleKeyword;
ADDRETAINTYPE(BREAK);
```

The output of this rules will return an annotation `SellerName` on "FirstAvenue Mortgage" with feature `value` containing the desired output "FirstAvenue Mortgage   TN 12230".

Mind that this is not a general solution but rather an example how it can be done in the give case.